# Trying to write an equals method for a class containing array of objects

Tags: java, object-oriented

Im trying to write a College class equals method that compare the content of the arrays of the two objects of college class. So The method will compare the Student[] array in college object to other Student[] array in another college object and same for the teacher[] array. I have written an equals method for this, but it looks too long and not pretty. Is there a better way to write it?

**College Class**

```
public class College
{
  private Student[] student;
  private Teacher[] teacher;
  public College()
  {
    student = new Student[9];
    teacher = new Teacher[9];
  }

  public Student[] getStudent()
  {
    return student;
  }

  public void setStudent(Student[] student)
  {
    this.student = student;
  }

  public Teacher[] getTeacher()
  {
    return teacher;
  }

  public void setTeacher(Teacher[] teacher)
  {
    this.teacher = teacher;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object inObj)
  {// this equals method

    boolean isEqual = false;
    College inCollege = (College)inObj;

    if(student.length == inCollege.getStudent().length)
    { 
      for(int i = 0; i < student.length; i++)
      {
        if(student[i].equals(inCollege.student[i]))
        {
            isEqual = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if((teacher.length == inCollege.getTeacher().length) && isEqual == true)
    {
      isEqual = false;
      for(int i = 0; i < inCollege.getTeacher().length; i++ )
      {
        if(teacher[i].equals(inCollege.teacher[i]))
        { System.out.println("im in");
          isEqual = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return isEqual;
  }
}
```

**Student Class**

```
public class Student
{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Student()
  {
    name = "Samrah";
    age = 19;
  }

  public Student(String name, int age)
  {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
  }
  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age)
  {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object inObj)
  {
    boolean isEqual = false;
    if(inObj instanceof Student)
    {
        Student inStudent = (Student)inObj;
        if(this.name.equals(inStudent.getName()))
          if(this.age == inStudent.getAge())
              isEqual = true;


    }
    return isEqual;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    String str;

    return str = "name: "+name+" age: "+age; 
   }

}
```

**Teacher Class**

```
public class Teacher
{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Teacher()
  {
    name = "Sanjay";
    age = 45;
  }

  public Teacher(String name, int age)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

   public void setName(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age)
  {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object inObj)
  {
    boolean isEqual = false;
    if(inObj instanceof Teacher)
    {
       Teacher inTeacher = (Teacher)inObj;
        if(this.name.equals(inTeacher.getName()))
          if(this.age == inTeacher.getAge())
              isEqual = true;


    }
    return isEqual;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    String str;

    return str = "name: "+name+" age: "+age; 
   }
}
```

Trying to do something like this:

```
    boolean isEqual = false;

    if(inObject instanceof EngineClass)
    {
        EngineClass inEngine = (EngineClass)inObject;
        if(cylinders == inEngine.getCylinders())
        if(fuel.equals(inEngine.getFuel()))
            isEqual = true;
    }
    return isEqual;
```

but with since its an array I have to loop through the arrays so I'm really confused.

Comment: Please post code as it is in your IDE, so that it compiles.  If you want to annotate the code, do it first in your IDE to make sure it still compiles.  Adding annotations that stop the code compiling (for example this: `**public boolean equals(Object inObj)`) make it harder to review.

Comment: If one college had students ['fred', 'foo'] and a second college had students ['foo','fred'] you wouldn't consider them equal (unless you have some sorting implemented that you've not shown us).  Is this by design?  Do you have to use arrays, or can you use other data structures like `Set`?

Comment: @forsvarir I only have to use arrays and yes it is by design.

Comment: If two colleges contain the students `['Fred', ..., 'George']` and `['Foo', ..., 'George']`, your method would return true, since the variable is always overridden, so only the last students are really compared. And then it gets overwritten again by the last teachers, so really it only compares the last teachers. Instead return false as soon as a mismatch is detected. This makes the code broken and off-topic for this site, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

1. It depends on what is exactly possible in your class - can you override class, can some fields be null at any point? For example retrofit creates classes using reflection and some classes can be very unexpectedly null unless set in constructor without parameters.
2. Many IDEs have generators, they do this really well.
3. If you override `equals`, you really should override `hashCode` too:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

I included equals generated by Android Studio - 2 possibilities, depending on if you are okay with subclasses too (hashcodes both same).

```
    @Override
    public boolean equalsV1(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        College college = (College) o;
        return Arrays.equals(student, college.student) &&
                Arrays.equals(teacher, college.teacher);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equalsV2(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof College)) return false;
        College college = (College) o;
        return Arrays.equals(student, college.student) &&
                Arrays.equals(teacher, college.teacher);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = Arrays.hashCode(student);
        result = 31 * result + Arrays.hashCode(teacher);
        return result;
    }
```

- You can notice, that there are static methods for arrays in `Array` class.
- Code is trying to exit as soon as it is sure, that equality isn't there rather than your approach, where code runs till the end and maybe it will set equals to `true` along the way, which has to run longer.
- You don't need to use getters, you can use fields directly since it's accessing fields of different instance, but same class.
- In `College` class it's fine, but in `Student` your class would crash if name is `null`. It shouldn't happen as even if your empty constructor you set it to something. But sadly in java I can still create `Student` class and pass `null` myself (would be good to do null check there). So just to be safe, equals should be able to handle that. There's method for that to make it easier - `Objects.equals(name, other.name)` rather than `name.equals(other.name)`. First one will work fine and return false when `name` is null. Second one will raise `NullPointerException`.
- `equals` shouldn't ever throw `Exception`. If you aren't sure to guarantee that, it might be better to just surround code in try-catch and return `false` on exception.
- Unless it's exercise, try to rely on these generators. They are pretty good and worked well for me.
- Now I switched to `kotlin`, that has data classes, which automatically have `equals` and `hashCode` based on all class properties already saves work and lines of code!

Comment: I am trying to do something of this sort: boolean isEqual = false;
       
     if(inObject instanceof EngineClass)
     {
  EngineClass inEngine = (EngineClass)inObject;
  if(cylinders == inEngine.getCylinders())
   if(fuel.equals(inEngine.getFuel()))
    isEqual = true;
     }
  return isEqual;

Comment: The versions that you have given are all good but are very high level for me as I still do not know anything about hashCodes.

Comment: Ye I added comments on generated code.